# Fit the text in web view screen in android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a case where I am using a web view to make a viewer for displaying unicode characters.

I want that the web view becomes un-scrollable, and whatever text I put in the web view, fits exactly on the web view 100%, i.e., the user shouldn't have to scroll up/down etc.

The text should take as much space as available in the web view, not less, not more.

Any help?

Or even Web View is the right tool for it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why or if you need a WebView. It would seem though that a simple TextView would do the trick. In that case, you can iteratively adjust down the text size with something like:

```
    yourTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, maxTextSize);
    reducedTextSize = maxTextSize;
    while( yourTextView.getPaint().measureText(colorName) > screenWidth ){
    yourTextView.setTextSize( --reducedTextSize );
```

Comment: I need to use WebView because the text I want to display might contain HTML for decoration etc. Any suggestions?